# Передача props, как параметра в функцию в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент, в который входят 2 других компонента: кнопки и блок, кнопок несколько, и при нажатии на кнопку, блок должен принимать ее цвет. Не могу понять, как в функцию, которая меняет цвет блока, передать нужный цвет кнопки.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
    this.state = {
      color: 'green'
    };
   this.handleSetColor = this.handleSetColor.bind(this);
  }
  //как сюда передать props из кнопки?
  handleSetColor() {
    this.setState({
      color: color
    })
  }

  render() {
   return(
     <div>
       <Button color={'green'} onClick = {this.handleSetColor}/>
       <Button color={'red'} onClick = {this.handleSetColor}/>
       <Button color={'yellow'} onClick = {this.handleSetColor}/>
       <Button color={'blue'} onClick = {this.handleSetColor}/>
      <ColorContainer color={this.state.color}/>
    </div>
   ) 
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
   return(
     <button onClick={this.props.onClick} 
             style={{backgroundColor: this.props.color}}
       {this.props.color}
     </button>
  ) 
  }
}

class ColorContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className={'color-cont'} style={{backgroundColor: this.props.color}}>Color container</div>
    ) 
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Документация просит так не делать
https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберните хендлер в функцию и передайте в нее цвет, в качестве аргумента. Так же укажите параметр цвета в хендлер.

```
...
handleSetColor(color) {
    this.setState({color: color})
}
...

const Button = props => {
    const {color, onClick} = props;

    return(
        <button onClick={() => onClick(color)} 
                style={{backgroundColor: color}}>
            {color}
        </button>
    )
}
```